# how to change the same background color of each shape in group shape

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am doing a project in asp.net mvc3 web app using canvas and fabric.js.I have an issue while doing, I have a group shape in that more than 3 rectangles joined together to make it one shape. Now the issue is after drag and drop the group shape from div to canvas the background color of group shape should change to gray but the background color is changing for one object shape in group shape.Here is the code so far, I have done for changing the color

```
 function drawActiveShape(x, y, type) {
        if (activeObject != null) {
            hideToolMenu();
            activeObject.left = x;
            activeObject.top = y;
            js_c_drawing.add(activeObject);
            if (type == 1) {
                activeObject.set('fill', 'gray');
                js_c_drawing.setActiveObject(activeObject);
            } else {
                activeObject.item(0).set('fill', 'gray');
                js_c_drawing.setActiveGroup(activeObject);
            }
            js_c_drawing.calcOffset();
            fabric.instances.push(js_c_drawing);
        }
        activeObject = null;
    }
```

can anyone tell me how to change for group shape, thanks in advance

after removing item(0) from else condition the background color is changing but dragging and dropping is not working and one more thing in item(0) if we place 1 it is changing the shape color means it will change to next object. 
I kept the else condition like this

```
else {
   activeObject.item(0).item(1).set('fill', 'gray');
   js_c_drawing.setActiveGroup(activeObject);
}
```

drag and drop operation is working but background color is not changing for any object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved by changing one word that is change group as object

```
if (type == 1) {
                activeObject.set('fill', 'gray');
              js_c_drawing.setActiveObject(activeObject);
            } else {
                activeObject.item(0).set('fill', 'gray');
                js_c_drawing.setActiveObject(activeObject);
            }
```